# Correct way to return an error code for function returning size_t

Tags: c

I have a function that probes an array and returns an array index if the probe succeeds.

In my code I have made every type concerning an array index a `type_t` for clarity.

What is the preffered way of retaining that clarity for this function? Should I take a pointer argument to an error variable and set that?

```
inline size_t
lin_search(const double *pxa, const double x, const size_t idxlow, const size_t idxhigh)
{
    for (size_t i = idxlow; i < idxhigh; i++)
    {
        if (pxa[i] <= x && pxa[i+1] > x)
            return i;
    }

    return -1; // If I change the return type to f.ex long int this works
               // but I am no longer consistent

}
```

Then I could use it as

```
index = linsearch(parray, x, 0, n - 1);
if (index == -1)
    ... not found
```

Comment: Could you switch your functions to the (signed) `ssize_t` instead?

Comment: I don't have `ssize_t`. Could you return `SIZE_MAX` to indicate failure?

Comment: `ssize_t` is not standard C (it's POSIX). C does have `ptrdiff_t`, though. That said, `(size_t)-1` is (AFAIK) always defined to be `SIZE_MAX`; one could perhaps just use `#define LIN_SEARCH_ERR ((size_t)-1)` or similar.

Comment: Oh and, you could do similar to what `strstr()` does --- return a pointer into `pxa`, or `NULL` if not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One other way without "losing" size_t (size_t *is* the correct type for array indexes) is to return the index value in the pointer and *return code* as a boolean:

```
    bool 
    lin_search(...., size_t *index) {
        bool found = false;

        for (size_t i = idxlow; i < idxhigh; i++)  {
            if (pxa[i] <= x && pxa[i+1] > x) {
               found = true;
               *index = i;
               break;
            }
        }

    return found;
}
```

and you can call:

```
size_t index;

if ( lin_search(...., &index) ) {
  /* use 'index' */
 }
```

This way, you don't have to compromise with using something other than `size_t` and the function return type still says whether the index is found.

Comment: I think this keeps things very consistent, thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Another short style question that may perhaps not warrant a brand new question: In my prototypes I add `const` to every parameter I do not intend to change, even for those values that `C` passes by a copied value by default (i.e. `int`s) like this `fn(const double x)`: is this good practice? Thanks again

Comment: @luffe It's harmless. But I personally don't think it's useful in anyway. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724051/const-correctness-for-value-parameters and

Answer (score 1):

Situations like this are not unheard of.  Take for example the definition of `fgetc`, which reads characters:

> ```
> int fgetc(FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> fgetc() reads the next character from  stream  and  returns  it  as 
>   an unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error.

This function returns a value that can be cast to `unsigned char` on success, and it return `EOF` (typically -1) on failure.

Another example is `ftell`, which reports the current offset in a file:

> ```
> long ftell(FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> Upon successful completion, ... ftell() returns the current
>          offset.   Otherwise,  -1  is  returned and errno is set to indicate the
>          error.

File offsets are always non-negative, so returning a negative value is how errors are reported.

So I think changing the return type to `long` would be acceptable for a case like this.