# C++ closure syntax error

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, closures

What is wrong with the syntax here? I follow [this](http://candrews.net/blog/2011/07/understanding-c-0x-lambda-functions/) resource.

```
char x = 'a', y = 'a';

[&x,=y]() { // error: expected identifier before '=' token
  ++x; ++y; // error: 'y' is not captured
}();
```

I use MinGW g++ 4.5.2 command line compiler with `-std=c++0x`

**clarification**: I'd like to pass `y` by value.

Comment: to increment the value of `y`, it has to be captured by reference.  To capture by value just writing `y` is sufficient. no need to write `=y'

Comment: @AdityaKumar all true but the OP is just trying to compile an example from a blog post where the blog author specifically passed the second parameter by value to show that the effect of the increment does not affect the closed over variable (because pass by value is a copy).

Comment: Capture by value by default cannot be modified. Various questions about it, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501959/why-does-c0xs-lambda-require-mutable-keyword-for-capture-by-value-by-defau

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char x = 'a', y = 'a';

[&x,y]() mutable{
  ++x; ++y;
}();
```

[Live example.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/f2b27f8a17fb1d37f50ab5fca844cca2)

Is the correct code. To capture a variably by-value, just write its name. To allow modification of by-value captures, the lambda needs to be marked `mutable`, otherwise the `operator()` is marked `const`.

`§5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda] p5`

> [...] This function call operator is declared `const` (9.3.1) if and only if the *lambda-expression*’s *parameter-declaration-clause* is not followed by **mutable**. [...]

Comment: Your live example uses C++11, is this valid C++03 syntax?

Comment: @Wolf the question is about lambdas.