# lambda capturing & const objects

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda

Suppose I have the following structure :

```
struct A {
    A() { std::cout << "default constructor" << std::endl; }
    A(const A&) { std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl; }
    A(A&&) { std::cout << "move constructor" << std::endl; }
    ~A() {std::cout << "deleting" << std::endl; }

    void update() { std::cout << "updating" << std::endl;}
};
```

I have a generic function that will interact with a reference of A :

```
void sync_process(A&) {
    /// ...
}
```

I want to process an instance in a different thread. Here is the code I use (basically) :

```
struct B {

    std::list<std::thread> threads;

    ~B() {
        for(std::thread& th : threads)
            th.join();
    }

    void thread_process(A& a) {
        // call sync_process in another thread for a copy of A
    }

};
```

And the main code would be something like this :

```
    B b;
    {
        A a;
        b.thread_process(a);
    }
```

Note that `a` may be deleted just after calling `thread_process`.

### Attempt 1

I first tried something like this :

```
threads.emplace_back([=]{sync_process(a);});
```

I expected the capture to let me use the reference, considering I got my own copy of `a`. But I was surprised to get a `const A` instead, resulting the following error :

```
// invalid initialization of reference of type 'A&' from expression of type 'const A'
```

### Attempt 2

```
A cpy(a);
threads.emplace_back(&sync_process, std::move(cpy));
```

This time : this weird error appears `no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<void (*(A))(A&)>'`. However, using a constant reference on `sync_process` prevent this error.

### Attempt 3

```
threads.emplace_back([&]{A cpy(a); sync_process(cpy);});
```

This time, I'm making the copy in the thread. But I won't have any guarantee that my object is still alive at this moment, right ?

### Attempt 4

```
A* cpy = new A(a);
threads.emplace_back([=]{sync_process(*cpy); delete cpy;});
```

OK, it works but it's not very safe : exceptions ...

So here are my questions :

1. Why the lambda capture "const-qualify" my object ?
2. What is the more elegant way to achieve this ? (store data with the thread, duplicate copies, ...)

Comment: Try a mutable lambda.

Comment: may be dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5501959/476681

Comment: Nice topic, thank you.