# C++ lambda copy value in capture-list

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a program as below:

```
int main()
{
    int val = 4;
    auto add = [val](int a)->int{
        val += 2;
        return a+val;
    };
    cout << add(3) << endl;
    cout << val << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There's a compiling error in Xcode: Cannot assign to a variable captured by copy in a non-mutable lambda.

My question is: if we choose to use the copy (using "=" or value name), can't this value be assigned a new value or changed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does C++0x's lambda require "mutable" keyword for capture-by-value, by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501959/why-does-c0xs-lambda-require-mutable-keyword-for-capture-by-value-by-defau)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Inside a lambda, captured variables are immutable by default. That doesn't depend on the captured variables or the way they were captured in any way. Rather, the function call operator of the closure type is declared `const`:

> This function call operator or operator template is declared `const`
>   (9.3.1) if and only if the lambda-expression’s
>   *parameter-declaration-clause* is not followed by `mutable`.

Therefore, if you want to make the captured variables modifiable inside the body, just change the lambda to

```
auto add = [val] (int a) mutable -> int {
    val += 2;
    return a+val;
};
```

so the `const`-specifier is removed.

Answer (score 12):

The `operator ()` of a lambda is implicitly `const` unless the lambda is declared `mutable` - and you can't modify the data members in a `const` member function. This happens regardless of the type of the capture.

Answer (score 3):

Just capture it by reference, it will work !!

```
 auto add = [&val](int a) -> int{ 
       //
}
```

Comment: Please, nobody do this. It will work until it explodes.

Comment: @Steazy why might it explode?

Comment: If the object that `val` refers to goes out of scope, this will "explode". For example, this could be the case when you return the lambda from a function.

Comment: To echo other commenters. Don't do this. Effective Modern C++ by Scott Meyers, Item 31 has a paragraph specifically saying *not* to do this