# Why are lambda arguments passed by value read-only in C++11?

Tags: c++11, lambda

When a function takes an argument by value, it can usually modify it. However, this does not seem to be the case with lambdas. Why?

```
int main()
{
  int x = 0;
  auto lambda = [x] { x = 1; }; // error: assignment of read-only variable ‘x’
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: By default, the closure's apply-operator is `const`. You can still modify the captured variables with `mutable`: `[x]() mutable { x = 1; }` See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5501959

Answer (score 13):

Herb Sutter answered the question [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3424.pdf) as follow;

> Consider this straw man example, where the programmer captures a local
>   variable by value and tries to modify the captured value (which is a
>   member variable of the lambda object):

```
int val = 0;
auto x = [=](item e)            // look ma, [=] means explicit copy
            { use(e,++val); };  // error: count is const, need ‘mutable’
auto y = [val](item e)          // darnit, I really can’t get more explicit
            { use(e,++val); };  // same error: count is const, need ‘mutable’
```

> This feature appears to have been added out of a concern that the user
>   might not realize he got a copy, and in particular that since lambdas
>   are copyable he might be changing a different lambda’s copy.

Note: That is a proposal paper to change the feature.

Comment: Has it changed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21228590/1353549