# How to fix error assignment of member, in read-only object?

Tags: c++

I have the following function:

```
void editItem(http_request message, std::string attributeToChange, std::vector<std::string> path, std::vector<Item>& items)
{
    message.extract_json().then([=](pplx::task<json::value> task) {
        try {
            std::string strId = path[0];
            int id = stoi(strId);

            for (auto &it: items) {
                if (it.id == id) {
                    json::value val = task.get();
                    int newState = val[U(attributeToChange)].as_number().to_int32();
                    it.state = newState;
                    message.reply(status_codes::OK);
                    break;
                }
                message.reply(status_codes::BadRequest);
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception &e) {
            message.reply(status_codes::BadRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

and in line: `it.state = newState;` I have  error like this: `error: assignment of member ‘Item::state’ in read-only object`.

This is how Item struct looks like:

```
struct Item
{
    int id;
    int state; //0,1,2
    std::string title;
    std::string description;
    std::string owner;
    std::string startDate; // string in format DD-MM-YYYY
    std::string endDate; // string in format DD-MM-YYYY
    std::string priority; //low/medium/hihg
};
```

There is no `const` inside. I don't know where coulde be a problem.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: [=] -> [&] perhaps

Comment: aside the compilation error, note that you are capturing items by value, and you are modifying a copy

Comment: Your logic in the loop seems bad... Should you really "reply" with a "Bad request" message for ***each*** item that doesn't match the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, when you capture by value, the copied `items` are read-only. Work-around, capture by reference (and you'll also avoid an unnecessary copy):

```
message.extract_json().then([&](pplx::task<json::value>
```

To be honest, this suprised me. After doing some research:

> This feature appears to have been added out of a concern that the user might not realize he got a copy, and in particular that since lambdas are copyable he might be changing a different lambda’s copy.

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714616/why-are-lambda-arguments-passed-by-value-read-only-in-c11/27715105#27715105).