# Generalized Lambda Capture Expressions in Visual Studio 2015: Compiler bug or correct behavior?

Tags: c++, lambda, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to move a vector into a lambda, but I get a compile error:

```
std::vector<int> vec {1,2,3};
auto lambda = [vec2 = std::move(vec)](){
     vec2.push_back(1);
}
```

The error is error C2663: "2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer"
It is generated in the line `vec2.push_back(1)`

when I change the example to

```
std::vector<int> vec {1,2,3};
auto lambda = [vec2 = std::move(vec)](){
     auto vec3 = std::move(vec2);
     vec3.push_back(1);
}
```

it compiles and works.

So is this behavior correct and if so, why can `vec2` not be modified?

Comment: Use `mutable`, so that lambda call is not const.

Comment: So after a quick search (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501959/why-does-c0xs-lambda-require-mutable-keyword-for-capture-by-value-by-defau)) I see that this has nothing to do with the move capture but is always the case when capturing by value. Very strange that after all this time of using lambdas it is only now that I encounter the behavior.

Comment: If you copy the example with the mutable keyword in it into an answer I will give you the points ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code does not have to do anything with generalized lambda capture. By default, lambda's call operator is `const` and thus, objects captured by lambda will be treated as `const`. You can use `mutable` keyword. That will make lambda's call operator non-`const` allowing you to modify captured objects.

```
std::vector<int> vec {1,2,3};
auto lambda = [vec2 = std::move(vec)]() mutable {
     vec2.push_back(1); //              ^ note
}
```