# C++ Lambda -- String params not working in following function calls

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm having an issue where when I try to access a string that's the main param in a lambda, the compiler doesn't recognize it as so when I try to call functions using that string.

Here is my code:

```
void removePunctuation(std::vector<std::string> &inTokens,
                   std::vector<std::string> &outTokens) {
std::for_each(inTokens.begin(), inTokens.end(), [outTokens](std::string s) {
    std::string newS = s;
    // newS.erase(std::remove_if(newS.begin(), newS.end(), ispunct));
    outTokens.push_back(newS);});
}
```

And the following error is produced:

```
a2.cpp:114:19: error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
    outTokens.push_back(newS);});
```

I am also getting this sort of error in other functions, when I try to call a function that uses the lambda's string param in its call.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean `std::for_each(inTokens.begin(), inTokens.end(), [&outTokens](const std::string& s) {std::string newS = s; outTokens.push_back(newS);});`

Answer (score 5):

By default, lambda arguments are [passed as read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5501959), try

```
[&outTokens](std::string s)
```

(It is perhaps what you want anyway, if the `outTokens` parameter is expected to be modified.)

Answer (score 2):

Aside that you should capture `outTokens` by reference, `std::transform` suits this better:

```
outTokens.resize( inTokens.size() );
std::transform(inTokens.begin(), inTokens.end(), outTokens.begin(),
    [](std::string s) {
        s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), ispunct));
        return s;
    } );
```

If you pass `std::string` by value you do not need to create yet another copy to modify it and first parameter to `removePunctuation` should be const reference.

Comment: However, now it seems to be erasing every single token that I end up printing. My call is as follows:    while (getline(inFile, line)) {
        replaceHyphensWithSpaces(line);
        std::vector<std::string> initialWords, words;
        splitLine(line, words); 
        removePunctuation(initialWords, words);

Comment: I put there exact logic as you showed in your code, if you need it work different way create another question

Answer (score 1):

You should capture `outTokens` by reference:

```
void removePunctuation(std::vector<std::string> &inTokens,
                   std::vector<std::string> &outTokens) {
    std::for_each(inTokens.begin(), inTokens.end(), [&outTokens](std::string s)
       {
           std::string newS = s;
           outTokens.push_back(newS);
       });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables captured by copy can't be modified, unless you make lambda [mutable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Explanation).

> mutable   -   allows body to modify the parameters captured by copy, and to call their non-const member functions
>
> Unless the keyword mutable was used in the lambda-expression, the function-call operator is const-qualified and the objects that were captured by copy are non-modifiable from inside this `operator()`.

e.g.

```
[outTokens](std::string s) mutable { ... }
```

But this means you'll modify on copy of `outTokens`, which might not be your intent. (Modify on a copy and then return doesn't make much sense.) You might want change it to capture by reference:

```
[&outTokens](std::string s) { ... }
```