# [C++]why map<> become const type in lambda expression

Tags: c++, lambda

Get the error `error: passing 'const std::map<int, int>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]` when codes below work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    std::map<int, int> test_map;
    std::vector<int> test_vec({0,1,2,3});
    test_map[0] = 1;
    test_map[1] = 2;
    for_each(test_vec.begin(), test_vec.end(), [test_map](auto i) {
        if (test_map.find(i) != test_map.end()) {
            test_map[i] += 10;
        }
    });
    return 0;
}
```

In lambda capture list, test_map is a non-const container, but it become const in the lambda body. why?

Comment: Why are you passing `test_map` by value, if you want to modify this map ? Should be `&test_map`, which resolves your problem. Now, you capture `test_map` by value, so you can only read this map inside lambda because by default `operator()` of closure is const qualified (`operator[]` of map is non-const function member). If you want really to modify copy of map, mark lambda as `mutable`.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo yeah, the key of map is **const**,  but it does not change the key,  it changes the value.

Comment: @liangzelang So it does ... :-) My bad. `[&test_map]` should fix that as rafix07 mentions.

Comment: rafix07 is right and this is probably a duplicate. See: [Why is a lambda's call-operator implicitly const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53445857/why-is-a-lambdas-call-operator-implicitly-const)

Comment: @Blastfurnace Great question that you have pointed to. Thank you.