# Why are insert iterators not copyable?

Tags: c++

The classes `std::back_insert_iterator`, `std::front_insert_iterator` and `std::insert_iterator` cannot be copied. Both the assignment operator and the constructor do not allow copies. Also the properties `container` (and `iter` in `std::insert_iterator`) are protected.

I wonder why. I'd like to copy these into a lambda function to use later to populate the containers.

Something like this doesn't seem possible:

```cpp
template<class OutIter>
std::function<void()>
generateFunction(OutIter out_iter) {
    return
        [out_iter] // not possible and a reference becomes dangling
        () { 
            // write to outpit iterator.
        }
}
```

I'm just wondering why? It would be handy to be able to use the iterators here. Now I either have to build my own inserter or work directly on the containers.
Or does anyone have another idea?

**Edit:**
It seems to be copyable. But if i use it as a lambda capture, i got a const version of the inserter.
This code does not compile:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template<class OutIter>
inline std::function<void(int)>
generateFunction(OutIter out_iter) {
    return
        [out_iter] (int value) {
            *out_iter = value;
            ++out_iter;
        };
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    auto myFn = generateFunction(std::back_inserter(v));

    myFn(1);
    myFn(2);
}
```

Error is:

```
<source>:10:13: error: passing 'const std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int> >' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   10 |             *out_iter = value;
```

**Solution**: The Lambda has to be `mutable`:

```cpp
template<class OutIter>
inline std::function<void(int)>
generateFunction(OutIter out_iter) {
    return
        [out_iter] (int value) mutable {
            *out_iter = value;
            ++out_iter;
        };
}
```

Many thanks for the helpful answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53445857/why-is-a-lambdas-call-operator-implicitly-const

Comment: *But if i use it as a lambda capture, i got a const version of the inserter.* You need to make you lambda `mutable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The classes `std::back_insert_iterator`, `std::front_insert_iterator` and `std::insert_iterator` cannot be copied. Both the assignment operator and the constructor do not allow copies.

Your assumption is wrong. All of the iterators mentioned must satisfy the  [LegacyOutputIterator named requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/OutputIterator) which implies that they also satisfy the [LegacyIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator) named requirement which requires the iterator to be copyable

Gcc, clang and MSVC all consider the iterators to be copyable, [see godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:30,endLineNumber:11,positionColumn:30,positionLineNumber:11,selectionStartColumn:30,selectionStartLineNumber:11,startColumn:30,startLineNumber:11),source:%27%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%23include+%3Citerator%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Ausing+Bi+%3D+std::back_insert_iterator%3Cstd::vector%3Cint%3E%3E%3B%0Ausing+Fi+%3D+std::front_insert_iterator%3Cstd::vector%3Cint%3E%3E%3B%0Ausing+Ii+%3D+std::insert_iterator%3Cstd::vector%3Cint%3E%3E%3B%0A%0Astatic_assert(std::copyable%3CBi%3E)%3B%0Astatic_assert(std::copyable%3CFi%3E)%3B%0Astatic_assert(std::copyable%3CIi%3E)%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:gsnapshot,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:clang1500,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2B20%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+3/15%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Comment: There might be issues arising from copying the `std::function` object so returned, when capturing single-pass output iterators

Comment: Ok, i have edited my question. How to copy one of the insert iterators into a lambda? It seems to be converted into a useless `const` iterator.

Answer (score -4):

```
template <class Container>
  class insert_iterator :
    public iterator<output_iterator_tag,void,void,void,void>
{
protected:
  Container* container;
  typename Container::iterator iter;

public:
  typedef Container container_type;
  explicit insert_iterator (Container& x, typename Container::iterator i)
    : container(&x), iter(i) {}
  insert_iterator<Container>& operator= (typename Container::const_reference value)
    { iter=container->insert(iter,value); ++iter; return *this; }
  insert_iterator<Container>& operator* ()
    { return *this; }
  insert_iterator<Container>& operator++ ()
    { return *this; }
  insert_iterator<Container>& operator++ (int)
    { return *this; }
};
```

Comment: Please read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). And probably about [`std::iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) as well. And don't try to get others into the same [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) as you seem to have fallen into.