# error: passing ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ as ‘this’ argument of ...discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, websocket, stdstring, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

I am trying to implement Websocket client using Cpprest sdk (Casablanca). I am successful in establishing the Web Socket connection and able to send/recieve messages. The response is received as an instance of websocket_incoming_message, which has a method, extract_string() whose definition is,

```
_ASYNCRTIMP pplx::task<std::string> web::websockets::client::websocket_incoming_message::extract_string (       )   const
```

Hence it returns, const string.

I am trying to assign this string to a function local string variable, so that I can return it to the calling method. However, I receive the below error,

```
error: passing ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

Below is my code block,

```
   std::string WebSocketUtility::send_command(const char* command){

    websocket_outgoing_message o_msg;
     std::string ws_response;

    o_msg.set_utf8_message(command);
    client->send(o_msg).then([](){
        log("Message Sent!!!\n");
    });

    client->receive().then([ws_response](websocket_incoming_message i_msg){ 
           return i_msg.extract_string();
        }).then([ws_response](std::string ws_body){ 
                 ws_response = ws_body;  
        });

   log("WS_RESPONSE:%s:\n",ws_response.c_str());
    return ws_response;
  }
```

I have tried 
1.Declaring ws_response as a reference
2.Capturing ws_response as a reference in lambda
3.Declaring ws_response as cpprest json, and assigning the response as a json field (ws_response[U("output")] = json::value::string(ws_body.c_str()))

with no luck.

I do not have much coding experience in C++ and struggling with this.

Could someone please help me on how to capture this response outside the lambda so that I can return the value to the calling method?

Thanks & Regards,
Swathi Desai

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501959/why-does-c11s-lambda-require-mutable-keyword-for-capture-by-value-by-defau).

Comment: "*Hence it returns, const string*" - that is not what the `const` means in this context.  It means `extract_string()` itself is `const`, ie it can be called on a `const websocket_incoming_message` object. The actual return type of `extract_string()` is `pplx::task<std::string>` (not `std::string`), there is no `const` on the return value. `pplx::task` has a `get()` method to get the actual `std::string`.

Comment: I think the error says that there is a const std::string & A assigned to a std::string & B which is not allowed because a modification of B would also modify A. The line is already complex. Doesn't give the compiler the position?  Is _ASYNCRTIMP pplx::task<std::string> maybe converted to a non const reference?

Comment: @ErnieMur The `const` that the OP refers to is the `const` at the end of the `extract_string()` declaration. Re: the error message, what you describe is not what the error means, either. The error is complaining that `operator=` is being called on a `const std::string` as the destination, not the other way around. And besides, modifying B after assigning to it does not also modify A, that is not how `std::string` works. And `_ASYNCRTIMP` is not part of the return type, it is just a macro that resolves to `__declspec(dllimport|dllexport)`. The return type is simply `pplx::task<std::string>`

Comment: You mean this, which generates a similar error message here with gcc:: const std::string a; a = someOtherString;    ?

Comment: @ErnieMur yes, that is basically what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

> `[ws_response](websocket_incoming_message i_msg){ return i_msg.extract_string(); }`

There is no reason for the above lambda to capture `ws_response` at all, as it does not use `ws_response` for anything.

> `[ws_response](std::string ws_body){ ws_response = ws_body; }`

The above lambda needs to capture `ws_response` **by reference** in order to modify it properly.  The way the lambda is currently coded, it captures a *copy* of `ws_response` **by value**, and that *copy* is `const` since the lambda is not declared as `mutable`.  This is why you are getting the compiler error - you are trying to assign `ws_body` to a `const std::string` object that is local to the lambda, not to the `ws_response` variable that is declared in `send_command()`.  The above lambda is *roughly* equivalent to this:

```cpp
const std::string ws_response_copy = ws_response;
ws_response_copy = ws_body; // <-- ERROR
```

Try this instead:

```cpp
client->receive().then([](websocket_incoming_message i_msg){ 
    return i_msg.extract_string();
}).then([&ws_response](std::string ws_body){ 
    ws_response = ws_body;  
});
```

Alternatively, `extract_string()` returns a `pplx::task<std::string>`, which has a `get()` method to retrieve the actual `std::string`, waiting until it is available. So the above can be simplified to the following:

```cpp
client->receive().then([&ws_response](websocket_incoming_message i_msg){ 
    ws_response = i_msg.extract_string().get();
});
```

Comment: Nice explanation .I have never used lambda in C++ yet therefore I tried to figure out where the error could be (before I read your answer). I could not find because ws_response is not defined const and it is not obvious to me the there is a const copy made somewhere in between. You have made two modifications. I guess the first use of ws_response without any assignment would not have caused any error? It  is only the second lambda?

Comment: @ErnieMur Yes, it is the second lambda that is failing to compile, which your compiler should have pointed out to you. Have a look at [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for what a lambda is and how it works.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I had tried capture by reference earlier. Compilation would succeed, however the value was not getting captured in ws_response. I was printing the ws_response outside lambda, and it was empty all the time. "Alternatively, extract_string() returns a pplx::task<std::string>, which has a get() method to retrieve the actual std::string, waiting until it is available.", this triggered an idea that, I may not be waiting for the response to be available.

Comment: Added a wait() method as below,   client->receive().then([&ws_response](websocket_incoming_message i_msg){ 
           ws_response = i_msg.extract_string().get();
        }).wait();  and I am able to capture the response in the variable now. Thank you for the suggestions.