# lambda capture by reference changes variable without mutable keyword

Tags: c++, lambda

When lambda expression's captures by reference( `[&]` ) marking `mutable` or not it still changing the value. But capturing by value needs `mutable` to change the object.

```
int main(){
   int x = 10;
   auto ByValue = [x](){ --x; }; // error: decrement of read-only variable 'x'
   auto ByRef   = [&x](){ --x; }; //No Error
   auto ByValM  = [x]()mutable{ --x; }; // No error
   auto ByRefM  = [&x]()mutable{ --x; }; // No error
}
```

[link to the demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sfb4vaKqK)

Why `[&x](){ --x; };` is able to change the variable `x`? Is it that capturing by reference marks the lambda expression `mutable` implicitly?

Comment: _"...`mutable`: allows body to modify the objects __captured by copy__, and to call their non-const member functions..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda  Capture by reference is capture by reference.  No need for `mutable` is changing the value of the reference it not  changing the value of the lambda just the referred to object, the lambda can still be const.

Comment: By reference is mutable,  unless it's a const object or const reference. Only capture by copy is const by default

Comment: Thank you guys. I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/5501959/12582758 it solves my question.

Comment: @RichardCritten Perfect makes sense now. Thank you.

Comment: @Yelp since it solved your problem I added it as duplicate for future readers