# Is it bad practice to make lambdas mutable?

Tags: c++, lambda

The following lambda doesn't compile:

```
auto l = [a = std::vector<int>() ]  {
                        a.resize(1);
                    } ;
```

That is because the variable captured by value a is automatically typed as const.
The following lambda should compile (although it doesn't on Visual Studio 2019 apparently):

```
 auto l = [a = std::vector<int>() ] mutable {
                        a.resize(1);
                    } ;
```

What is the rationale for transforming a into a const vector automatically in the first place ?
It feels like I'm doing something wrong by forcing the lambda to be mutable.
Was this done to prevent accidentally modifying the closure parameters in case I want to execute the lambda several times?

Comment: case (2) needs to be `auto l = [a = std::vector<int>() ] () mutable { a.resize(1); } ;` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/szjrjbeGv

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21228590/7703564) answer gives some insights on the issue of mutable lambdas.

Comment: There are nothing wrong to have no `const` methods/objects. It is just that, in C++ the default, except for lambda, is mutable instead of `const`.