# How do you cast away const'ness when the function takes a reference to the object (and access non-const methods)?

Tags: c++, casting, constants

I have a back up copy of data that I would like to protect so I made it `const`. I need to violate that `const`ness on two occassions, once to store virgin data to it:

```
fgBlocks.CopyInto((BlkArray&)backUpCopy);
```

w.r.t.

```
result CopyInto(BlkArray &replica) const {/**/}
```

and again when I call `RemoveAll()` on it which is a non-const method:

```
((BlkArray)backUpCopy).RemoveAll(true);
```

Is the first cast (shown above, `(BlkArray&)`) correct? It's the one aspect of indirection I haven't cast to before now. Then again I'll add another unused aspect, that of casting away `const`ness for calling an object's methods, which the compiler isn't accepting as shown above.

The members are declared like this:

```
BlkArray fgBlocks;
const BlkArray backUpCopy;
```

I'm trying to extend Correa's solution so have:

```
    BlkArray *pBUCopy = (BlkArray *)&backUpCopy;
    fgBlocks.CopyInto(*pBUCopy);
```

Only problem now is the compiler is failing due to

> uninitialized member 'MyClass::backUpCopy' with 'const' type 'const BlockArray'

Comment: Better to use `const_cast` rather than C-style casts.  Makes it more obvious to the reader than constness is being cast away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Be aware that if you do this and the object really is `const`, then modifying it after casting away the `const`ness is undefined behaviour.

```
fgBlocks.CopyInto(const_cast<BlkArray&>(backUpCopy));
```

Same thing for the other one:

```
const_cast<BlkArray&>(backUpCopy).RemoveAll(true);
```

Comment: The object really is `const`. Apart from the above calls, I made it a `const` member and is only otherwise used in a read-only capacity. The call to `RemoveAll` comes in the destructor of the containing class.

Comment: @John unfortunately you can't do what I posted then without causing UB. What you may want to do is make the real variable `private` and _not_ `const`, then make a `const` _reference_ to it `public`. This way, the class it is a member of can modify it, but the outside world can only look at it through the `const` reference and so cannot change it.

Comment: @John: Why do you need to call `RemoveAll`? Just let `BlkArray`'s destructor deal with removing the data.

Comment: I've got an accessor for that, I'm more concerned about this class, and classes which extend, it having write access other than for the two occassions defined above.

Comment: @Xeo: I'm afraid it's part of the two phase construction idiom, I need to supply `true` so it can deallocate its elements.

Comment: @John so you, the implementor, are trying to protect yourself from the implementation?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I'd just want an easier life 8) I might need to extend this class _very_ heavily and I recall being told that `const` was just "noise" when placed before parameters in the method declaration http://stackoverflow.com/a/9213503/866333

Comment: @John: If it's a *value* parameter, that's an important distinction. Also, it's not *before*, it's *after*. `void f(int const value)` is the same as `void f(const int value)` and should look like that in the definition, while the declaration should just be `void f(int value)`

Comment: @Xeo: I now appreciate it is less effort to omit `const` from declarations, but I _like_ to have my declarations accurately depict the actual definitions.

Comment: @John: An interface (declaration) should *not* tell you something about the implementation details (definition).

Comment: @Xeo: I guess I fail to appreciate the distinction of value vs ref parameters. I use the latter so oftern I almost take it for granted that that is what I meant. Sorry, over-zealous migration from C to C++.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little trick I learned looking at Qt's internals:

```
MyClass:circunventConst() const
{
    MyClass* that = const_cast<MyClass*>(this);
    that->myProtectedVariable = value;
}
```

Comment: That's a few more lines than I'd hoped but seems right for me, thanks, I'll give that a go.

Comment: This doesn't help at all (if, as the poster said, `myProtectedVariable` is `const`, it is `const` whether or not `*this` is `const`). Also, this causes undefined behaviour if `*this` is really a `const` object. Qt is <strike>stupid</strike> silly for doing this.

Comment: Well, I'm talking from memory, so can't give specifics why it was done or if it's still in Qt's code. But it sure was the first time I saw that. Of course, for this simple example, the proper way would be myProtectedVariable to be mutable so it would be valid for a const method to change it. It maybe that they saw bugs in compilers with mutable and were working around it, but then I'm just expeculating.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Thanks man! I'll just give it a really <strike>stupid</strike> obscure name to keep it safe.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: So the purpose of `const_cast<>` is to make a pointer to `const` not. And it can only safely do that if the object pointed to is not declared `const`?

Comment: @John not only pointers, but references too. And your second sentence is almost but not quite correct: it can make a pointer or reference to an object that is declared `const` not `const` perfectly fine; the bad thing happens when you _modify_ the object that was declared `const` through the non-`const` pointer or reference you got from using `const_cast` to cast away the `const`-ness. _Then_ is when you get UB. The way to think of it is that `const_cast` casts away the `const`-ness of the type of the reference, but it doesn't actually make the underlying object non-`const`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: That explanation is very good. _Then_ being synonomous with _run-time_, as opposed to the gentle prodding the compiler is currently giving.

Answer (score 0):

You can circumvent this problem by simply marking all methods as `const`, except `RemoveAll` and `CopyFrom`, the latter being made to be a method of `BlkArray` that either implements the logic or passes `*this` to `CopyInto`.

To be more secure about who can clear the data / copy new stuff into it, you may make those methods private and declare the necessary classes as friends, or use the [passkey pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3324898/500104) to protect those two methods.