# How do member functions pass the "this" pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, constants, this

Say I have a class `Foo` that has a member function which returns a non-const reference, that itself runs a member function that uses a const `this` pointer:

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo& display(std::ostream& os) { do_display(os); return *this; }
private:
    void do_display(std::ostream& os) const { os << contents; }
    std::string contents;
}
```

When `display` runs `do_display`, the `this` pointer gets implicitly converted to a pointer to const. Why is it, then, that when `do_display` terminates, `display` is still able to change the object it was called on? As far as I know, it's not possible to assign a pointer to const to a pointer to non-const normally. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: You can think of it like a parameter. if it has `const` added for one function, that doesn't affect the caller.

Comment: only `do_display` can't change the object. `display` can. there's no magic here, as `this` is passed as first (hidden) parameter.

Comment: Non-const methods can change the object just fine, even if they call a const one. A method is just like another function with a hidden "first" parameter.

Comment: you pass a parameter by value (the pointer's one) so you can do whatever you want

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I wasn't sure if "this" was an implicit parameter or something that gets implicitly returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the non-const pointer in `display` in order to pass it to `do_display` creates a new pointer of a different type; it doesn't change the type of the existing pointer. Passing `this` to a member function is very similar to passing an argument to a non-member function:

```
// A non-const member function receives `this` as a non-const pointer
Foo& display(Foo * this, std::ostream & os) {
    // Pass a copy of `this`, converted to `Foo const *`
    do_display(this, os);

    // The local `this` is still `Foo *`
    return *this;
}

// A const member function receives `this` as a const pointer
void do_display(Foo const * this, std::ostream & os) {os << this->contents;}
```

Comment: Did you experience the copying with newer compilers? I currently work mostly with the old-fashioned ones.

Comment: @Wolf: You don't "experience the copying", since the mechanism for passing `this` is hidden. The point is that passing it to another member function doesn't change its type in the calling function, in the same way that passing a normal argument wouldn't change the type of any local variables.

Comment: Ok, that's what I forgot: The `this` pointer is so omnipresent, that I didn't even remember that it has to be passed to member functions, and in cases like in the OP's example, the call will surely be optimized.

Comment: Shouldn't the first argument to `do_display` be declared as `const Foo* this` rather than `Foo const* this`? I always thought the `this` pointer was a "pointer to constant object".

Comment: @jia103 both forms mean the same.

Comment: @jia103: Both are equivalent. I usually put the `const` after the thing it qualifies for consistency; but you can put it before the first thing if you want.

Comment: I think there is a `is` missing in the last sentence of the description.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ `const` access is often only a **compile-time attribute** [1] that is introduced to ease the control of the object's state. [2]

The method `do_display()` does not change anything of `this` but it restricts the access to read-only in its scope. After the call of the `do_display()` method returned, the access is read-write as before in the scope of the `display()` method.

---

[1] that's the reason for the option to [*cast const away*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9474757/2932052), which can be considered safe if the constness is *only a declarative* one.

[2] see Item #3 in [Effective C++: 55 Specific Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs (3rd Edition): Scott Meyers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) or for example [Const Correctness - C++ Tutorials - Cprogramming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html)