# C++ diffrence between const & to regular &

Tags: c++, reference, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of 'const' for function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117293/use-of-const-for-function-parameters)

I am new to C++, came from java programming so the Reference weird uses in C++ comes unnaturally to me. I am not a new programmer, so I'd appreciate a serious deep and wide answer about this subject rather then just a shallow "when to use" only answer.

I want to know what are the differences between

```
const A& p;
```

and

```
A& p;
```

Comment: First is const, second is not. What is unnatural here? o.O

Comment: @Griwes - what is unnatural is that Java and the .NET languages do __not__ have a clear concept of `const`-ness, which to (good) C++ programmers looks like a significant omission.

Comment: @AAT, wait, are we supposed to use Google for OP, or to be OP's "living encyclopedia"? Plus, we should ban teaching Java or .NET languages before C++...

Comment: @bmarguiles how can this be a duplicate of a question that does not mention references and asks about function parameters only?

Comment: @Griwes, I wasn't disagreeing with you, just making a slightly tongue-in-cheek point about Java and .NET. Maybe I should have put a <g>!

Answer (score 3):

`const A& p` is a reference to a constant object of type `A`.

`A& p` is a reference to a (non-const) object of type `A`.

Comment: `const A& p` is a const reference to an object of type `A` which may or may not be `const` itself.

Comment: @Ferruccio: No. there is no such thing as a "const reference" in C++. What would it mean? A reference is *never* mutable, in the sense that you can never set it to point to a different object. You have references to const objects and references to non-const objects. But you don't have const references

Comment: Could it be less informative? you didnt help me at all..

Comment: @OfekRon: then perhaps you should be clearer about what you want to know. And perhaps you should drop the attitude, because I was actually trying to answer your question (unlike all the others who voted to close it). What exactly is it you don't understand? Do you know what a const object is? Do you know what a reference is?

Comment: @jalf - Yes, of course the reference itself is never mutable. That was a poor choice of terms on my part. What I meant is that if you write `const A& p = q;`, even though `q` may be mutable, you can't change it through `p` without invoking undefined behavior.