# Using the final modifier with mutator methods

Tags: java, c++, mutators

In C++ you could write

```
Int getX() const { return x; }
```

Is there an equivalent method structure in Java using final?

What about passing const/ final modified arguments to methods?

Like this C++ code

```
void printX(const int x);
```

Comment: It would help java programmers to answer if you told them what this does.

Comment: @tieTYT it tells that the class state is not modified when this method is called.

Comment: So if you pass a reference to the object as a `const` parameter, the method can be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the C++ example:

```
void printX(const int x);
```

you can use `final` modifier in method parameters to indicate the parameter can't be modified inside the method:

```
void printX(final int x) {
    System.out.println(x);
    x++; //compiler error since `x` is marked as final
}
```

Note that using `final` modifier for object reference variables just means that the reference can't be modified, but its inner contents still can:

```
class Foo {
    int x = 0;
}
class Bar {
    changeFoo(final Foo foo) {
        foo.x = foo.x + 1; //allowed even if `foo` is marked as final
        foo = new Foo(); //compiler error...
    }
}
```

---

From SJuan76 comment for this code

```
Int getX() const { return x; }
```

> it tells that the class state is not modified when this method is called.

There's no way in Java to mark a method like this.

Comment: If you pass `final List<Integer> ints` - it can't be modified?

Comment: That would be equivalent to `printx (const int x) {...`, not what the the OP is asking for.

Comment: @dantuch `ints` can't be modified i.e. `ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();`, but its content can.

Comment: @SJuan76 OP's question is pretty ambiguous to begin with.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You could add something about the use of `final` on methods in java...

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza when you say `parameter can't be modified inside the method` it's true only for immutables (and privities, which are immutable) because the only thing that cannot change is the reference to passed parameter - its internal state can be changed if it's possible.

Comment: @dantuch yes, I know this. Answer updated for clarifying this.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what about `static`? It doesn't prevent static members from being changed but essentially since there is no instance it is under certain conditions stateless?

Comment: @zsawyer `static` modifier in Java can be understood as *it belongs to the class, not to the object reference*. Based on this premise, a getter method should not be `static` at least that the field to retrieve is also `static`.

Comment: I agree with Luiggi that there seems to be no way to do that in Java. It is one of the few C++ features that I found more useful than in Java (there are a couple more in C#)

Comment: [Good reading](http://stackoverflow.com/q/117293/1497596) on whether it is considered a good practice to declare parameters passed by **value** (copied) as `const`.

Comment: @DavidRR yes but this applies more for C++. In Java usually this won't be a problem since [Java is pass by value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1065197).