# Why does not used constant pointer at strcmp in cstring.h

Tags: c++, string, constants

In cstring.h file there exists a function:

`int strcmp ( const char *s1, const char *s2 )`, but why only the data is constant, isn't it more safe to make both pointer and data constant.In my opinion the correct version of function should be like:

```
int strcmp ( const char * const s1, const char * const s2 )
```

Comment: There is no `cstring.h`. There's `cstring` and `string.h`.

Comment: I agree. Although, it makes absolutely no difference to the caller whatsoever. I do try to do this though.

Comment: In a declaration, it's extra noise. In a definition, it's generally a good idea to make whatever you can `const`.

Comment: @chris The definition can be const while the declaration isn't?

Comment: @Ben, It sure can as long as they're top-level.

Comment: Just for completeness, parameter *names* are also ignored in declarations.

Comment: @FredOverflow Good point. `int strcmp( char const* s1, char const* s2 )` and `int strcmp( char const* const x, char const* const y)` both declare the same function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of 'const' for function parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117293/use-of-const-for-function-parameters)

Comment: Well, at least parameter names in those declarations have a use: The client gets a hint what those parameters are for.

Comment: @James You don't even have to bother the parser with meaningless names: `int strcmp(const char*, const char*);`

Comment: @Deduplicator It depends. I would argue that if you name your parameters `s1` and `s2` or `x` and `y`, then you could just as well leave the names out completely.

Comment: @Fred: Of course you can use meaningless names. x, y, n and the like might be short, but depending on the function name, they may convey all the information needed. (Just for on-upmanship, your absolute does not reign unconstrained. ;-) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Top-level const modifiers of parameters are stripped from declarations, because they do not concern the client. Whether parameters are changed or not is an implementation detail. It is perfectly valid to declare a function as `void f(int x)` and then later define it as `void f(const int x)` (and vice versa).

In your example, even if `s1` and `s2` are modified inside `strcmp`, the client does not notice these modifications, because the pointers are passed by value (copied into the function). That is, if you call `strcmp(a, b)`, then `a` and `b` will retain their values, even if `str1` and `str2` are changed.

Comment: But isnt it recommended to use const , if you dont change values

Comment: The client does not need to know (and has no way of knowing) whether `s1` and `s2` are modified inside `strcmp`. There would be no point in adding the `const`. The compiler strips it out, anyway.

Comment: @DavutÖzcan Maybe this wasnt stated clearly here: Passing by value will result in a **copy**, thus const is completely meaningless for the caller, as there is **no way** that his passed arguments could be modified, whether const or not.

Comment: @FredOverflow And typically, top level `const` isn't used for local variables anyway.  (Whether this is a good thing or not is another question, but in all of the different companies I've worked in, only one ever used const on local variables.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: amusing, I tend to use it for any variable that will not vary.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes.  That's the policy here, as well, but this is the first place I've seen it.  (IMHO: if your functions are long enough that you can't immediately see whether a local variable is modified or not, they're too long.  But it depends somewhat on the application domain; in numeric processing, functions tend to be longer than elsewhere, and the `const` can be useful.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: actually, I use it even on very small functions; for example `Val* find(std::map<Key,Val>& m, Key const& k) { auto const it = m.find(k); return it != m.end() ? &it->second : nullptr; }` :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. There's nothing wrong with that, either; it's just not been the usual practice in places where I work.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the top level const is ignored in
the declaration; the most frequent convention I've seen has been
to forbid it.

It does have meaning in the definition.  But the most frequent
implementation of `strcmp` is something like:

```
int
strcmp( char const* s1, char const* s2 )
{
    while ( *s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0' && *s1 == *s2 ) {
        ++ s1;
        ++ s2;
    }
    return (unsigned char)( *s1 ) - (unsigned char)( *s2 );
}
```

The parameters *aren't* const.

Comment: `*s1 != '\0' && *s1 == *s2` implies `*s2 != '\0'`; no need to check `*s2 != '\0'` explicitly.

Comment: @FredOverflow And there are probably other improvements which could be made as well:-).  The only real point is that all of the implementations I've seen do use the arguments directly, modifying them.

Comment: The most prominent example probably being `while ((*dst++ = *src++));` inside `strcpy` ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow As an example of what not to do:-).  But yes, such code has existed (and been supported) since the earliest days of C.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary. As the pointers are copied, I don't see how adding one more `const` makes anything safer?

And, most probably, the implementation *changes* the `s1` and `s2` pointers (probably in some loop, incrementing both pointers to compare each `char`, one by one).

Comment: Yes it is possible to implement algorithm by changing pointer values , but reverse is also possible.Same algorith can be implemented using '[]' operator.

Comment: @DavutÖzcan It could be, but it would be very unidiomatic.

Comment: @DavutÖzcan - what James says is true, plus it will lead to adding (at least) one more variable - index, which will slower down the execution (yes, it's a minor thing, but it's something).