# C++ boost conditional type not accepting function arguments

Tags: c++, boost

I have been experimenting with the boost headers for conditional data types.  I would use `std::conditional` but I need backward compatibility for non-C++11 compilers.

So, the following works if I explicitly declare a `const int` within the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <boost/mpl/if.hpp>

using namespace boost::mpl;

void f()
{

  const int j = 1;
  typedef typename if_c<j == 1, float, int>::type condType;

  condType a;

  std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;

}

int main()
{
  f();

  return 0;
}
```

I initially thought I would try to pass the `const int` as a function parameter but I get a compiler error (see end of question).

```
void f(const int i)
{

  typedef typename if_c<i == 1, float, int>::type condType;

  condType a;

  std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;

}
```

I have learned from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117293/use-of-const-for-function-parameters) that I can't really have `const` in a function parameter.  So I also tried declaring a `const int` on the argument.

```
void f(int i)
{
  const int j = i;

  typedef typename if_c<j == 1, float, int>::type condType;

  condType a;

  std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;

}
```

but I continue to get the compilation error.

> boost_test.cpp: In function ‘void f(int)’:
>   boost_test.cpp:11:25: error: ‘j’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
>      typedef typename if_c::type condType;

Any thoughts on how I can pass a parameter to a function that conditionally sets the type?

Comment: You can't, as function parameters are not known at compile time. You can make a template function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler needs to know the value of `i` when this line

```
typedef typename if_c<i == 1, float, int>::type condType;
```

is compiled. Since `i` is an argument to the function, compiler can not predict what the argument going to be, and can not compile your function.

You can use template function (with `int i` as a template parameter) to achieve what you want.

For example:

```
template<int i> void f() {
  typedef typename if_c<i == 1, float, int>::type condType;

  condType a;
  std::cout << typeid(a).name() << "\n";
}

int main()
{
  f<1>();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you provide an example of such a template function?