# Is function parameter constness mismatch allowed?

Tags: c++, macos, abi, name-mangling

Regarding [using `const` function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117293/use-of-const-for-function-parameters) I've heard that on some OS X systems the constness of a parameter is mangled into the function signature. For example, if one would have the following declaration in an interface header file:

```
int f(int argument);
```

but if one would only implement this function:

```
int f(int const argument);
```

then this might lead to a linking failures on OS X (but not on Linux) because the OS X way to mangle C++ function signatures includes the constness of the parameters.

Which is the correct mangling behaviour? Does the C++ standard have a say on this?

Comment: _`int f(int const argument);`_ is pretty redundant, but well if you insist that it's meaningful.

Comment: Out of interest, where did you hear this?  This would be very broken, if true.

Comment: The correct behavior is to ignore top-level `const`, which means `const` that applies to the parameter itself (as opposed to something to which the parameter refers). For example, `int *const` and `int *` are the same, but `int const *` and `int *` are different. Hard to believe OS X would have a compiler that gets this wrong though (it's a really basic part of C++ that's been well known since long before OS X existed).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth About 2 years ago some co-workers noticed some of the code not linking on OS X due to such mismatches, therefore I've tried to avoid such ever since. I don't remember exactly what toolchain they used.

Comment: @jotik That sounds unlikely. Can you reproduce it?

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry I don't have any OS X systems nearby.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Just tested this with XCode 7.3 (Clang & G++/GCC), OSX El Capitan 10.11.4. ideone.com/kQzNgm and ideone.com/IJR3vu Links fine (dynamically and statically both tested).

Doesn't matter whether or not I make the parameter const. The above code is what I used for testing dynamic linking. 

Also tested with pointers (dynamically). Same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top-level const and volatile qualifiers should be ignored for the purposes of name mangling.  This can be determined from two things in the standard.  The first, is that a function's signature is used for name mangling.

In the C++14 standard, section 1.3.17 defines a signature:

> name, **parameter type list (8.3.5)**, and enclosing namespace (if any) [ **Note: Signatures are used as a basis for name mangling and linking.** — end note ]

To get the definition of a parameter type list, we then refer to section 8.3.5/5:

> The type of a function is determined using the following rules. The type of each parameter
>   (including function parameter packs) is determined from its own decl-specifier-seq and declarator. After
>   determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or “function returning T” is
>   adjusted to be “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T,” respectively. After producing the list
>   of parameter types, **any top-level cv-qualifiers modifying a parameter type are deleted when forming the
>   function type**. The resulting list of transformed parameter types and the presence or absence of the ellipsis
>   or a function parameter pack is the function’s **parameter-type-list**. [ Note: This transformation does not
>   affect the types of the parameters. For example, int(*)(const int p, decltype(p)*) and int(*)(int,
>   const int*) are identical types. — end note ]