# Best way to remove string prefix from std::string_view?

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

As of C++20 `string_view` has `remove_prefix` but it is "wrong"(wrong for my usecase) thing.
It takes as an argument number of chars, instead of a prefix(string like thing).

I have [this](https://godbolt.org/z/j1anzd) code, but I wonder if there is some nicer way to do what I want(note that my code cares about if prefix was removed so I return boolean):

```
static bool Consume(std::string_view& view, const std::string_view prefix)
{
    if (view.starts_with(prefix))
    {
        view.remove_prefix(prefix.size());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

note: I know I could return `optional<string_view>` instead of bool + out arg, but that is a different style discussion, I mostly care about having something like nonexistant

```
bool /*prefix removed*/string_view::remove_prefix(string_view prefix);
```

note2: tagged this C++17 because that is when `string_view` "arrived", I am fine with any C++20 alternatives.

Comment: This seems pretty nice to me. What do you not like it? What would you like to improve? I would probably just change the function name to `remove_if_prefixed` or something like that.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili maybe there is some STL algorithm or some other member function I did not think of...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I mostly care about having something like nonexistant
>
> ```
> bool /*prefix removed*/string_view::remove_prefix(string_view prefix);
> ```

Indeed, such function is not in standard library. But you've now written such function, and your function is thus a nicer way to do something like what you want.

---

If you're open for a different design, I would suggest following alternatives:

```
constexpr std::string_view
remove_prefix(std::string_view sv, std::string_view prefix) noexcept
{
    return sv.starts_with(prefix)
        ? sv.substr(prefix.size())
        : sv;
}

// usage
string_view no_prefix = remove_prefix(view, prefix);
bool was_removed = no_prefix.size() != view.size();
```

Or return a class:

```
struct modify_result {
    std::string_view result;
    bool modified;
};

constexpr modify_result
remove_prefix(std::string_view sv, std::string_view prefix) noexcept
{
    return sv.starts_with(prefix)
        ? modify_result{sv.substr(prefix.size()), true}
        : modify_result{sv, false};
}


// usage
auto [no_prefix, was_removed] = remove_prefix(view, prefix);
```

I'm not saying these are better for your use case. These are just alternative solutions which may apply to different use cases.

Comment: Why did you remove `const` from the arguments?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Keeps the declaration more readable due to not having irrelevant information.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili FWIW, top level const on value parameters is meaningless from the callers perspective.  `int(int)` and `int(const int)` are the same thing.  You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117293/use-of-const-for-function-parameters#:~:text=It%20is%20not%20recommended%20to,side%20effects%20outside%20the%20function.&text=%22Google%20C%2B%2B%20Style%20Guide%22%20%22Use%20of%20const%22%20section)

Comment: @NathanOliver it often prevents accidentally modifying the values I didn't mean to. This is a definition, not just a declaration, so I think it'd be nice to spread the, perhaps subjectively, better style in a public forum like this. It's just a matter of style, of course, but `const` by default, mutable if needed is a nice style imo.

Comment: Definitely subjective, because I strongly disagree. If you const-qualify top-level argument types, it looks like it should allow overloading on argument constness, but this is not possible. Since top-level const qualification is [explicitly stripped](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct#5) from the function type, it feels misleading.

Comment: @Useless it helps with reading function implementation, even if useless for function declaration.

Comment: Yes, reading comprehension is also subjective. I do just fine without it.