# about const keyword as a parameter in function

Tags: c++

I still don't understand what is the difference between these two code i mean if we put const

keyword in front of data type parameter in function  what happened to my our code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void function1(const int x);

int main(){

};
```

And if we don't put const keyword what happened  to our code?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void function2( int x);

int main(){


};
```

Comment: Try to do `x = 5;` in both functions and you will see the difference.

Comment: In your function _declaration_, it has no effect.  Your two code samples are equivalent.  In the function's _definition_, the variable is const.

Comment: @keamvireak `const` lets you express you are not going to modify that parameter within the function; the compiler will make sure you don't do it: https://godbolt.org/z/zY8f1rPcY

Comment: The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117293/use-of-const-for-function-parameters) may shed some light.

Comment: In the code examples provided, the `const` in the declaration as used in this code has no affect on the code, and there is no difference.  The `const` does not even affect the signature of the declaration (i.e., the mangled name is the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [const](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/const-cpp?view=msvc-160) keyword prevents a variable from being modified.

It mostly used to prevent an object that is passed by reference from being modified. It can also prevent mistakes at compile time like writing = instead of == in boolean statements.

In your case, the variable is passed by value and not by reference. In both function declarations, the variable inside the function is a copy of the variable you pass to that function. This means that even if you change a variable that is passed by value, its value will only change inside the scope of that function.

Relate to this [article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) about scoping.